# Finding the intersection of a line segment (one point inside the rect, one outside) and a rect side

Tags: math, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to guide the player to the last enemy on the field, via having an icon on the edge of the screen pointing towards the last enemy outside the screen.

The screen is the rectangle, the player is the point within the rectangle, and the enemy is the point outside of the rectangle.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXBeN.png)

The solutions I can think of are finding which side will be intersected (Which I'm not sure how to do correctly, but I imagine first involves finding if it will be intersecting on vertical or horizontal sides) and then using a linear equation to find the x or y. Or, you could use a line-line-intersection method on each side, but as the screen rect never changes, this seems a little overkill.

I've got my first solution working on paper for one test case, but can't get it working at all with in Unity.

Does anyone have a solution or could push me in the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rectangle edges have equation

```
X = XLeft
Y = YBottom
X = XRight
Y = YTop
```

Player-enemy vector

```
D = (D.X, D.Y) = (E.X - P.X, E.Y - P.Y)
```

if D.X is positive, consider intersection with right edge (otherwise with left)

```
P.X + t * D.X = XRight
```

if D.Y is positive, consider intersection with top edge (otherwise with bottom)

```
P.Y + u * DY.Y = YTop
```

Solve equation for t and u. If `u` is less than `t`, intersection with horizontal edge goes first, and find X-coordinate of intersection with expression

```
XInt =  P.X + u * D.X
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Would there be a way to detect if the enemy is within the rect during the algorithm? Right now I just check if it's in the rect before, and if it is I cancel calculating the intersection.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to detect if the enemy is within the rect - `t>1` and `u>1`. But checking against the rect is simpler, so I think -  it is worth to make it is before calculation.